# Tabular or two column mode

Tags: two-column

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
![alt text][1]\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{l l|l l}
\underline{\textcolor{blue}{Text 1}}& \hspace{1cm} &\hspace{1cm} & \underline{\textcolor{blue}{Text 2}}\\
&&&\\
Derivation of Text1 &&& Derivation of Text 2\\
Same as shown above &&& Same as shown above
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am achieving this using tabular environment. I was wondering if there is any other way to split the document into two column wherever i have need to produce such results. 
[image]
Thanks for y

PS can I post example code with unicode text (i.e. Devanagari or Sanskrit)

Comment: Yes, you can post Unicode here.  I'd edit it in, but I can't type Devanagari and don't know Sanskrit :-)  But go ahead, use Unicode if you want!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{parallel} 
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{Parallel}[c]{}{} 
\ParallelLText{% 
\underline{\textcolor{blue}{Text 1}}}

\ParallelRText{% 
\underline{\textcolor{blue}{Text 2}}}

\ParallelPar

\ParallelLText{% 
\parbox{\ParallelLWidth}{%
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item B 
\end{enumerate}} 
Same as shown above 
} 

\ParallelRText{% 
\parbox{\ParallelRWidth}{%
\begin{enumerate} 
\item C 
\item D 
\end{enumerate} }
Same as shown above } 

\end{Parallel} 

\bigskip new text line here defined paper area 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Herbert,Thanks for showing me how to do parallel however I could not itemize things on both sides. When I used itemize then both are getting over lapped on the left side. Is there a way around it.

Comment: @Aku, please give an example

Comment: @Aku: see my edited example. I do not know if this is the right way because I used the parallel package only for pure text where I can have left the original text and on the right the translated text.